# Jquery UI-Selectable "Multiple Instances"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is this possible?  I sure hope it is.  I have multiple instances of ui-selectable and I when I click through them I want the other instances to toggle off as well.  Currently it toggles one of each div.  Is there a way to modify my javascript or something to make them toggle both instances?

Example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(".ui-selectable").selectable();
});
</script>

<div class="ui-selectable">
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ui-selectable">
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

$('.ui-selectable').each(function (){     $(this).toggle(); });

Comment: everything shows up but it still displays the other instance as selected unfortunately.

Comment: Could you set the id attribute for this div's? So when you'll work with 'div1' (for example') you'll hide 'div2', and vice versa. This would work for you, would not?

Comment: That could would.. Can I see example?

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function (){
  $("#btn").click(function (){
   if($(bt).parent().attr('id') == 'div1')
   {
    $("#div2").hide();
   }
   else
   {
    $("#div1").hide();
   }
  });
 });
</script>

<div class="ui-selectable" id="div1">
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="test" id="btn" />
</div>

<div class="ui-selectable" id="div2">
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="test" id="btn" />
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are making the DIV selectable, when it should be the unordered list (ul).  Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H8fPL/21/.  Let me know if you need anything else.

**EDIT:**

I think this is what you are looking for.  Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H8fPL/60/

I have also provided the code below....

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( ".selectable" ).selectable({
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var el_id = $(this).children("ul").attr("id");

    $("ul.ui-selected").not("#" + el_id).each(function(index, element) { 
       $(element).toggleClass("ui-selected");
        if($(element).children("li").hasClass("ui-selected")){
           $(element).children("li").removeClass("ui-selected");
           }
    });
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="selectable">
<ul id="ul1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="selectable">
<ul id="ul2">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is actually not my problem.  I have two div's that have content that I want selectable in.  But I only want 1 selection to be visible at a time out of those two divs.